# Curl - Retrieve headers - empty response

Tags: php, curl

Using php when working with curl.

I'm attempting to only recive the headers.

I request from the following url: http://halens.se/kvinna-klader-bad-strand-baddrakter-93/baddrakt-074209/

My settings look like this:

```
  CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER     => true,
  CURLOPT_CERTINFO        => false,
  CURLOPT_CRLF            => true,
  CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT  => 15,
  CURLOPT_FAILONERROR     => true,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
  CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE    => true,
  CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT   => true,
  CURLOPT_HEADER          => true,
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS       => 15,
  CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS       => CURLPROTO_HTTP,
  CURLOPT_REDIR_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_HTTP,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 15,
  CURLOPT_HEADER          => true,
  CURLOPT_NOBODY          => true
```

But the response is empty.. **What did I do wrong?** or **How can we solve this in an alternative way?**

---

If I instead change the last setting to:

```
  CURLOPT_NOBODY          => false
```

Then I get the headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Length: 199
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: http://www.halens.se/kvinna-klader-bad-strand-baddrakter-93/baddrakt-074209/
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 06 Oct 2013 19:26:31 GMT

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 123009
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=wsp1hsdq1huvdnmr0jf42m1o; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=wsp1hsdq1huvdnmr0jf42m1o; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: FavoriteList=Id=593cd25e-3508-46a8-9596-66bd45caa335&Hash=PRHTFWRFDX; expires=Sat, 04-Jan-2014 20:26:32 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: InteractorId=wsp1hsdq1huvdnmr0jf42m1o_162_13_85_148; path=/
Set-Cookie: ClickTrail=074209; expires=Thu, 05-Dec-2013 20:26:32 GMT; path=/
X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 06 Oct 2013 19:26:32 GMT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an answer to the specific : It seems a little bit weird and googling around I can see other people have struggling with this issue also (without getting closer to an explanation) - but are you aware of the [`get_headers`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) function?

```
$header = get_headers('http://halens.se/kvinna-klader-bad-strand-baddrakter-93/baddrakt-074209/');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($header);
echo '</pre>';
```

outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
    [1] => Content-Length: 199
    [2] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [3] => Location: http://www.halens.se/kvinna-klader-bad-strand-baddrakter-93/baddrakt-074209/
    [4] => Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
    [5] => X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5
    [6] => X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    [7] => Date: Sun, 06 Oct 2013 21:17:44 GMT
    [8] => Connection: close
    [9] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [10] => Cache-Control: private
    [11] => Content-Length: 123078
    [12] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    [13] => Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
    [14] => Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=i5nrsl55e1shp4alanw3dlzu; path=/; HttpOnly
    [15] => Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=i5nrsl55e1shp4alanw3dlzu; path=/; HttpOnly
    [16] => Set-Cookie: FavoriteList=Id=51b514b9-21e8-4ed3-9ec9-38ef8a2df113&Hash=VKSZPIUFZX; expires=Sat, 04-Jan-2014 22:17:44 GMT; path=/
    [17] => Set-Cookie: InteractorId=i5nrsl55e1shp4alanw3dlzu_80_163_1_60; path=/
    [18] => Set-Cookie: ClickTrail=074209; expires=Thu, 05-Dec-2013 22:17:44 GMT; path=/
    [19] => X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5
    [20] => X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    [21] => Date: Sun, 06 Oct 2013 21:17:44 GMT
    [22] => Connection: close
)
```